# Horizontal blackberry file manager

Tags: blackberry, user-interface

i have a horizontal file manager on a screen ...and a vertical field manager inside the horizontal field manager..but the height of the vertical field manager increases and decreases due to adding and deleting fields dynamically... and the height of the horizontal file manager changes accordingly which i don't want...i want to fix the height of the horizontal file manager to a specific height..which would be max val for vertical field manager...

how can i do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL|Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR){
                    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                        maxHeight = specificHeight;
                        super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                    }
                };
```